# Align two DIV's and use entire page width

Tags: css

I need to align two div's inside a parent div.

The parent div should take up the page width with a margin on both sides.

The 1st child div should be 100px wide with a 4px margin. The 2nd Child div has to take up the rest of the space with a 4px margin on the right.

How do I write the CSS for this? I have written this so far

```
div.parent {

        width: ?;

        border:1px black solid;

        position: relative;

        clear: both;

        }

<div class="parent">

<div class="child1"> </div>

<div class="child2"> </div>
```

Comment: Folks here don't like writing your code for you.  Have go and update your question with the code you've come up with so far, and specific questions about any problems you're having.

Comment: You should google on "CSS 2 column layout" and you'll find lots of info to figure out this layout issue.

Comment: I do not know how to let the parent take entire width of page with a margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add the margin to the parent div?

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100%; padding: 4px; background-color: Yellow;">
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100px; background-color: Lime; position: relative; float: left; border: solid 1px black; border-right-width: 0px;"></div>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: Red; border: solid 1px black; border-left-width: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```